# Measurable and unmeasurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Is there any theorem shows that if we randomly choose a set from the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$，the possibility that it is measurable is $0$？

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There hardly is a probability on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly choose"? There is no natural uniform distribution on sets like $\wp(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: However, I recall reading on Royden's book that there is a model of analysis where AC is false and all subsets of $\Bbb R$ are Lebesgue-measurable. And of course, it should as consistent as standard analysis.

Comment: However: under AC, if you call $\mathcal L$ the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets, then $\lvert \mathcal L\rvert=\lvert \mathcal P(\Bbb R)\setminus\mathcal L\rvert=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, so there is no cardinality evidence to support your claim. As mentioned before, explicitly finding even one non-measurable subset should arguably be "impossible".

Comment: Yes, there is: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102386/is-a-random-subset-of-the-real-numbers-non-measurable-is-the-set-of-measurable/102409#102409

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Wow.